# Refinery cms page length more than 65534 bytes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I have a site and one page is very long. When I tried to save this page in refinery cms page editor, it saves only 65534 bytes in my mysql2 database, table page_part. I've convert field body in page_parts to medium text and it helps me to save page in database, but refinery still taking only 65534 bytes. Can I increase this?

Rails 3.2.2
refinerycms 2.0.2.

Comment: I have a problem saving large pages too in RefineryCMS. I tried to post a giant list of Questions and Answers to my blog and had to break it up because it would cut it off. You can see in this link that I had to create multiple posts to create this entry. http://shawnlindsey.com/blog/ruby-test-questions-the-great-big-ruby-test

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a mysql limitation. Mysql has a couple datatypes that can store more text, you'll need to create a migration to modify refinery_page_parts.body column to be either 'mediumtext' (16 million characters) or 'longtext' (over 4 trillion characters). Like this:

```
change_column :refinery_page_parts, :body, 'mediumtext'
```

or

```
change_column :refinery_page_parts, :body, 'longtext'
```

Comment: I did it, and it helps me to save page in database, but refinery still taking only 65534 bytes.